# SECURITY: exploring shared hosting with basic shell account

Tags: security, shared-hosting

Hello o just noticed that with my SHELL account on shared hosting i can list all current active PHP sessions basically (i can list them through ls ../../tmp).

Also i can also list all users (no passwords though)

Is it normal?

Answer (score 1):

Listing active session files is different from being able to read the contents of the actual files themselves, the first is among the [cons of shared hosting](http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/5.html), the second is a server misconfiguration.

The file **/etc/passwd** no longer stores security sensitive information, merely data that users are allowed to view about themselves, so this needs to be publicly readable. Passwords are stored in *shadow* files which are not world readable.

Comment: yeah ) i saw tha /etc/passwd is publically available and this is got me confused